# Math formula without space in Latex

Tags: spacing, xetex, unicode-math

I want to write script ***A:B::C:D*** But when I use following formula

```
(/A:B::C:D)/
```

it display it as ***A : B :: C : D***.

I want to know how to remove spaces between characters?

Comment: What are the semantics of this notation? Maybe a literate environment like `\lstinline` from the listings package is another option

Comment: the code `(/A:B::C:D)/` is very peculiar.  perhaps you mean `\(A:B::C:D\)`?  the colons have a particular semantic meaning in math that determines the spacing.  you can suppress the default spacing by wrapping each colon in braces: `{:}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just encase each instance of `:` in curly braces: `{:}`. Doing so will change the symbol's math status from "math-rel" to "math-ordinary".

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$A : B :: C : D$ vs.\ $A {:} B {:}{:} C {:} D$ 
\end{document}
```